# Taxonomies relation

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

We are new to Orchard. And we've created 3 taxonomies *Company*, *Brand* and *Model*.
A Brand has a Company as a field and like that Model contains a Brand.
Now, by defining a ContentType named *Car* which has Brand and Model as fields and in this view:

```
@*
    This shape displays a term and all content items associated to it.
*@
@{ Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("content-items"); }
@Display(Model.ContentItems)
```

We can get Company's logo like this:

```
Model.ContentItem.CompanyTerm.CompanyLogo
```

2 questions:

1. How is it possible to access Company's Brands?
2. And by having that Brand how can we retrieve all Brand's Cars.

Answer (score 1):

First, please be aware that there is a very high potential for select n+1 squared issues here.

Your company terms are themselves content items, so you can get to their parts and fields. This should work if the taxonomy field for the brands is called `Brands` and is attached to a part with the same name as the term's type:

```
Model.ContentItem.CompanyTerm.CompanyTerm.Brands.Terms
```

Each of those terms will be a content item, so in the same way, and if the cars are a taxonomy field called `Cars` on a part named `BrandTerm` on the brand taxonomy term type, this should get you the list of cars:

```
brandTerm.BrandTerm.Cars.Terms
```